# Trying to open pdf file in new browser window

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, window.open

Cant get the PDF open in new browser window. There is a php code I use to set the PDF and open it!

```html
<?php
if (($_POST['name_check']=="in") || ($_GET['type']=="in")){
 header('Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=windows-1257');
 header("Content-Disposition: inline; ");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 $file_type = "in";
 $flag = 0;
}
else{
 header('Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=windows-1257');
 header("Content-Disposition: inline;");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 $file_type = "out";
 $flag = 1;
}

?>
<?php session_start();  
 if (((isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) and (isset($_SESSION['Pin_code']))) and (isset($_COOKIE['CookieMy']))){
  $form='<form action="login.php" method="get" style="width: 900px;margin: -1px auto -57px auto;" class="exit_but">
  <input type="submit" name="exit" value="EXIT" style="margin-left: 800px;"></form>';
  echo $form;   
 } else {
  header("Location: login.php"); 
 }
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  idleTimer = null;
  idleState = false;
  idleWait = 1200000; 
  var theElement = document.getElementById("elem");

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind('mousemove keydown scroll click', function(){
   clearTimeout(idleTimer);
   idleState = false;
   idleTimer = setTimeout(function(){
      idleState = true;
      window.location.href = "login.php"     
   }, idleWait);
    });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

 function last(){
   if (($_POST['name_check'])=="in"){
    $type = '"pdf-in"';
    $flag=0;
    echo "<script>window.flag_in=false;</script>";
   }
   else{
    $type = '"pdf-out"';
    $flag=1;
    echo "<script>window.flag_in=true;</script>";
   }
   
  if (!isset($aircraftid)){
     $aircraftid = $_POST['hostcountry'];
     $aircraftid='"'.$aircraftid.'"';
   }
  if (!isset($date)){
    $date = $_POST['per1'];
    $date=date($date);
   }
  
  include ("config.php");
  
  //////////////////////////////////////////
  
  
  $mysqli = new mysqli($dbconf['host'], $dbconf['user'], $dbconf['password'], $dbconf['dbname']);
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   echo "MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  }
  
  $query = mysqli_multi_query( $mysqli, "SELECT dn_get_flight_file_name($date,$aircraftid,$type);") or die( mysqli_error( $mysqli ) ); 
  if( $query ) 
  { 
   if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
     while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
      $PDF_File_Name=$row[0];
     }
     $result->free();
    }
  }
  
  ///////////////////////////////////
  
  mysqli_close( $mysqli ); 
  $qwerty=$PDF_File_Name;

  
  ///////////////////////////////////
  $ftp .='ftp://'.$ftp_user.':'.$ftp_pwd.'@'.$ftp_server;
  
  if($flag==0){
   $file_path_ftp = $ftp_path_pdf_in.$qwerty;
   $file_path_local = "in/".$qwerty;
  }
  else{ 
   $file_path_ftp = $ftp_path_pdf_out.$qwerty;
   $file_path_local = "out/".$qwerty;
  }
  
   
   $file_path_ftp = trim($file_path_ftp);
   $file_path_local = trim($file_path_local);
   $file = $file_path_local;
   $current_content = file_get_contents($ftp.$file_path_ftp);
    file_put_contents($file, $current_content);
   $qwerty=$file_path_local;
  
  $date2 = $_POST['date'];
  $num = $_POST['num'];
  return array ($qwerty,$date2,$num);
 }

 if (isset($_GET['name'])){
  $qwerty=$_GET['name']; 
 }
 else {
  list ($qwerty,$date2,$num) = last();
 }
 if (!file_exists($qwerty)) {
  $file_path_local=$qwerty;
  $slash_occur = stripos($qwerty, '/');
  $file_type   = substr($qwerty, 0, $slash_occur);
         $file_name   = substr($qwerty, $slash_occur+1);
  if($file_type=='pdf-in'){
   $file_path_ftp = $ftp_path_pdf_in.$file_name;
  }
  else{ 
   $file_path_ftp = $ftp_path_pdf_out.$file_name;
  }
  echo "<h2>file_type = ".$file_type.", file_name = ".$file_name."</h2>";
  $ftp .='ftp://'.$ftp_user.':'.$ftp_pwd.'@'.$ftp_server;
  $current_content = file_get_contents($ftp.$file_path_ftp);
  file_put_contents($qwerty, $current_content);
 }

 if (isset($_GET['date'])){
  $date2=$_GET['date'];
 }
 if (isset($_GET['num'])){
  $num=$_GET['num']; 
 }
?>

<?php
if (($_POST['name_check']=="in") || ($_GET['type']=="in")){
 @readfile($ftp_path_pdf_in.$qwerty);
} else {
 @readfile($ftp_path_pdf_out.$qwerty);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to open PDF file in the new (Chrome) browser window.

```
document.action =window.open('date_PDF.php', 'newWindow', 'width=1000, height=1000');
```

Error is **Failed to load PDF document.**

When I do `document.getElementById("edit").action ="date_PDF.php";` it opens pdf.

I get the PDF file from the ftp server and than display it on date_PDF.php `@readfile($ftp_path_pdf_in.$qwerty);`

Where is the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Does `window.open()` take the correct path?

Comment: date_PDF.php needs to be open, so yes, it does take the correct path

Comment: You're mixing HTML, JavaScript and the PDF output. If you want to send a PDF you shall not send other content than the PDF!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined the name_check html element. Also you have not passed the 'type' parameter in the url. I think the name_check and type are present on the page from where you open the pdf file.

If you want to open the pdf file using window.open then you should use the url: date_PDF.php?type=in

After the readfile statement you should have an exit statement. See the example for the readline function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#refsect1-function.readfile-examples

Comment: I'll try to check this. Thank You!